# Internal Server Error when running multiple PDO statements

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a webpage that will display information based on a certain dropdown selection that a user will make. In order to see the data, I have multiple queries that run to determine which data will be displayed. If I am using just 1 query and pdo statement, it is working for me. However, I have multiple queries and pdo statements and when I try to use multiples, I get an `Internal Server Error`.

Can anyone offer some advice as to what the problem may be? Here is an example of what one of my queries and PDO statements look like:

```
$_400p_1_1 = "SELECT CAST([Program_ID] AS INT) AS Program_ID
      ,CAST([Series] AS INT) AS Series
      ,[Supplier_Group_Name]
      ,[Buyer Group Name]
      ,[Fund Name]
      ,CAST([Agreement_ID] AS INT) AS Agreement_ID
      ,[Location Group Name]
      ,[Product Group Name]
      ,[Shipping Group Name]
      ,CAST([Tier_ID] AS INT) AS Tier_ID
      ,[Retro_to_1]
      ,CAST([Payments per Year] AS INT) AS [Payments per Year]
      ,[Condition Unit of Measure]
      ,CAST([Condition Minimum] AS INT) AS [Condition Minimum]
      ,CAST([Condition Maximum] AS INT) AS [Condition Maximum]
      ,CAST([Incentive Multiplier] AS DEC(5,4)) AS [Incentive Multiplier]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[vExample]
  WHERE [Supplier_Group_Name] = '$supp' AND [Series] = 1 AND [Fund Name] = '400P' AND [Agreement_ID] = 1
  ORDER BY [Supplier_Group_Name]";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($_400p_1_1);
$stmt->execute();
$results1 = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

And here is an example of bringing in the information to display:

```
<label>Program ID:</label><input value="<?php echo $results1[0]['Program_ID'];?>" readonly>
```

I should also mention that the dropdown selection, which is in `page1.php`, is sent through AJAX to `update.php` where the queries and PDO statements are located, along with the other HTML/PHP code. Again, it works just fine though if I am only using one query and one PDO statement.

Comment: Check server logs to see what's exacly wrong.

Comment: are u sure the above code produces that error? also enable error reporting then inspect element on tht input the error will be there

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I guess I'm not 100% positive but I'm assuming it is because when I am just using the one query and statement instead of multiple ones, then it works and no error is produced

Comment: @Rataiczak24 try enable error reporting then I suspect `$results1[0]['Program_ID']`

Comment: With that piece of code being on my `update.php` page which is called through AJAX, since I am getting an Internal Server Error there is not a way for me to view that in my console is there?  Here is where I am at right now...Right click > Inspect > Network tab > update.php

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Don't use Inspect-element client console to view server-side error.  You need to enable error_reporting in php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1255289)